# Can one develop a program that can see and access the edits one makes to a file?

Tags: daemon, rootkit

I know about key loggers and root kits. I know it is possible for these programs to know what keys a user is pressing and what programs a user has open at any given time but, is it possible for a program (or background process) to know what commands (functions) with in a program are being executed?

e.g. A user is in Photoshop and does the following:

1. Opens the file called **mountain.jpg**
2. Crops 103 pixels off the top
3. Increases the Contrast by a value of 50
4. Saves the file as  **mountain-EDIT_1.jpg**

Can a background process (daemon) understand that a user ran Photoshop's **Open**, **Crop**, **Contrast** and **Save** functions?

To be more specific, can a background process:

1. gain access to those unsaved edits like **Crop** and **Contrast**
2. take that data and save it else where

Also how does one locate where a program like Microsoft Word, Photoshop or ProTools is saving each of the edits a user makes?

Comment: It would require to have access to the program stack to decode which instruction of its code is being run. If it is ever possible, it only can occur in the Kernel. The same goes to detect edits on a file : you must intercept what is being run on the filesystem level ...

Comment: This kind of feature is needed to record user actions to later then do autmated testing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_automation#Graphical_User_Interface_.28GUI.29_testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more close you would get to this functionality would be by using the photoshop's built-in scripts. I do not have enough knowledge to talk about this more, and I also doubt its the place to discuss this functionality.

On a more *programming oriented* point of view, you would need to look at memory photoshop is allocating for this image file and reverse-engineer photoshop's code to understand what happens on every edits you mentionned. I doubt its humanly possible.

If the user is saving the image after each edits though, you could watch for changes in the image, and try to look for the what you want to understand.

Comment: Photoshop may also be storing a history of the user operations. Finding this history and reverse-engeneering it would do the trick but again, the same wall gets erected ...

Comment: So in each operating system, is there one directory that an application stores each edit a user makes to a document? Or do different programs store edits in different folders depending on the program?

Comment: Each application stores the edits the way it decides to. Often, it will not even be written to disk, just stored somewhere in ram. You cannot describe a pattern of how each applications is implementing its undo functionality. Its up to the developers to decide it.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Photoshop plugin or script. But a generic software in such detail I don't think is possible.